# Url of the loaded html in an Iframe

Tags: iframe

We have a customer portal site hosted externally. 
I need to create a  page in our company site where in employees will use the page to login to the portal. The login page they offer is generic

To implement this, I am planning to create a page and then iframe (width: 200px ; height:100 px) the login page of the customer portal.   This way I can have the company branding on the login page..

But my problem is, when user logs in via the iframe, the resulting home page opens within the iframe window.

My question: is there a way to find the url of the page that is loaded in the iframe so that based on the url, I can change the dimensions of the iframe?

The src attribute of iframe always shows the login page url.

My Iframe code:

```
<iframe onload="loadMyFrame();"  src ="https://login.tomyportal.com" width ="370" height="200" id="sWindow" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function loadTest() {
  var ifr = document.getElementById("sfWindow");
  alert(ifr.src); //the value returned is always login page.
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
alert(ifr.location.href)
```

?